# Is doctrine 2 compatible with Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to install doctrine 2 on a Zend Framework 1.12.

I read somewhere that doctrine 2 easy to configure Doctrine 2 to Zend Framework 2. However, I am not clear whether Zend Framework 1.12 uses he same configuration or whether I need to use an adapter so something.

I ask because I heard that it was a nightmare to install doctrine 1 into the Zend Framework but that Doctrine 2 amended all these problems. I am not clear however if these amendment were retrospective.

Comment: If it is a new project, you should use Zend Framework 2! However, if you still insist on using ZF1, there are some examples out there. Here is one I did many years ago when Doctrine 2 first came out, it has not been supported for a while, but it should give you an idea https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-

Comment: hi eddie. i am still fairly new to Zend, so it would be really helpful to me if u could explain why u think i should use zend  2 over 1 . do you beleive that there are huge diffrences between the two?

Comment: Sure. There is a big difference between zf1 & zf2, here are a few reasons to use zf2 instead of zf1: zf2 uses event driven architecture which has many benefits & modular architecture, zf2 uses psr-* standards & composer to manage dependencies, zf1 will stop officially being supported next year (2014)...the list goes on. zf1 was great for the time, i.e. before zf2 was released last year

Comment: thank you Eddie. you have convinced me to work in Zend2. the only real problem is that all the leading books on zend are in zend1. i.e 'Zend framework in action' by Rob allen, 'Zend framework' by  vikram vaswani and 'Easy php websites with the Zend framework' by Jason gilmore.  All 3 books are exclusively written for Zend1. so, for newbies like myself, how do we learn the framework if we don't have access to the right books on it. it is for this reason that i started on zend1

Comment: We were all newbies at some point :). Use the quickstart guide http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/overview.html

Comment: Choosing zf1 vs zf2 is more a matter of how much time you have to get the project done. Zf2 has a lot going for it. But the learning curve is steep compared to zf1, and zf1 wasn't a walk in the park either. Only if you are NOT in a time crunch would I recommend starting with zf2.